# Can you have both clear: left and clear: right?

Tags: css, css-float

I want to preface this with the fact that I know there is `clear: both` but I looked at someone's code and they are using both `clear: right` and `clear: left`. Would this behave like `clear: both` or would only one clear attribute be executed?

Comment: @Gopi no it won't if both are used in the same element. The last one will override the previous one

Comment: @Gopi no, it wouldn't.

Comment: If they're doing that and not seeing any layout issues, then they were probably only floating in whichever direction ends up working, e.g. if their clear: left was effective, then the floats being cleared were only ever floating to the left. This can be easy to miss. But I'm more fascinated by the fact that they didn't use clear: both to begin with - the vast majority of people who learn about clear: both never find out about the left and right options!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to have both `clear: left` and `clear: right` is to use `clear: both` instead.

If you use both, for instance:

`<div style="clear: left; clear: right">`

then the last one will overwrite the first one. In this case, the div would be cleared to the right.